# Loading R package without root permission: libproj.so.0: cannot open shared object file

Tags: r, slurm, lib

I'm working in a SLURM server without root permission and I'm trying to load some R packages ('sp') to perform some analysis.

However, when I load the package I obtain the following error:

```
Loading required package: sp
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sp’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/tools/R/R-3.6.1/lib64/R/library/sp/libs/sp.so':
  libproj.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I checked where libproj.so.0 is located and I got these results:

```
/usr/lib64/libproj.so.0
/usr/lib64/libproj.so.0.7.0
```

My guess, by checking on similar problems on stackoverflow, is that I should create a symbolic link between `/usr/lib64/libproj.so.0` and `/usr/local/lib`. However, I do not have root permission to do it successfully.

Any suggestion on how to solve the problem?

Comment: Have you tried installing `sp` package to your own R lib folder?

Comment: Not yet. I will try, but I'm sure there has to be another solution, like specifying the libproj.so.0 path in some profile file.

Comment: Usually it's better to install your own library anyway. I don't think network admins are interested in keeping R packages updated. You also will have full control of what versions you want to run

Comment: Is this happening after submitting the script to Slurm? You need to make sure that all the nodes have the right privileges to access the package.